# Most innovative way to config a live application

Tags: configuration

Forget trivial apps that have half a dozen users and a dozen options, what ui do you think is most effective at letting the admin get the job done. Some interesting technologies which though have other applications might include:

- AREXX - "live" application scripting.
- GUIs - Point and click, a bit troublesome when one has lots of repetitive tasks.
- SHELLs/Cmd lines - aka like *nix shells, requires knowledge of whats "available" before one can update the right files etc.

*FORGET O/S*

My question relates to configuring a completely self contained application itself that does not read its config primarily from files on the filesystem. Please forget and assume the OS level stuff is done and the customisation of the app remains.

*CMD LINE OPTIONS*

Assume that this app is long lived and one wants to change options after it has started and restarts are not viable.

Comment: What does it do instead of reading its options from files on the filesystem?

Comment: Thats the question, maybe initially one might read from a file on the f/s but once the app is started the admin needs a way to change options etc that may originally have been expressed in some file.

Answer (score 2):

GUI + shell/cmd line options directly from GUI

Comment: Yes. For example, in linux GUI you can click right mouse button on file and change what software you want to open this file, but also you can define custom cmd to open this file. It is pretty useful sometimes. You can also implement this feature into your own GUI. Of course, you should allow adminstrator to use scripts only from allowed list (because of security). It's my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

An Administrator without *nix knowledge is not worth for the paid Money. 
I recommend using the Shell to config/update/maintain a Website

Comment: Forget the OS, im asaking about the app itself.